# Read Excel dynamic file reference using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to read excel file that has dynamic workbook reference to its cells using Python.
When I use openpyxl and read it, it returns the cells with the dynamic workbook reference as '=[1]Sheet0!T10'
instead of:

'='Q:\OPERATIONS\PERFORMANCE\ANALYSIS\2019[analysis.xlsx]Sheet0!T10'

I need the info about the file path that is referencing.
Here is a code to reproduce the issue:

```
1: from openpyxl import load_workbook
2: import pandas as pd
3: xls = r"C:\TEST\test.xlsx"
4: wb = load_workbook(filename = xls, read_only=True)
5: ws = wb("sheet1")
6: df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
7: ws["E11"].value
```

This returns '=[1]Sheet0!T10'

When I convert to dataframe at line 6, it returns df with values not formula, so this is not helpful.
Is there a better package or method to extract the referenced file path in python?

Comment: You'll need to look at the external links in the workbook.

Comment: Is there Python method in openpyxl to look for the external links?  There are 100s of these files and the code needs to look for any cell that references external files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Charle Clark with a clue to find a solution to this puzzle. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096323/identify-external-workbook-links-using-openpyxl) was available with answer to get the dynamic workbook reference within an Excel file.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.count(".xls"):
                try:
                    xls = os.path.join(root, name)
                    wb = load_workbook(filename = xls, read_only=True)
                    print(xls)
                except Exception as err:
                    msg = "ERROR: {} file failed to read!".format(xls)
                    print(msg)
                    print(err)
                    f.write(str(err)+"\n")
                    continue
                
                items = wb._external_links
                msg = "There are {} external links..".format(len(items))
                print(msg)
                if len(items) > 0:
                    xls_dict[xls] = []
                    for index, item in enumerate(items):                        
                        Mystr = wb._external_links[index].file_link.Target
                        Mystr = Mystr.replace("file:///","").replace("%20"," ")
                        print(Mystr)
```

This code could be simpler but gets the job done. Also, openpyxl does not open the old version of excel (xls), this needs to handle separately. You could filter out by searching for xlsx or release error message as shown above.